# detecting clicks and touch events with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, click, touch, ontouchlistener

Good day all.
I would like to get the timestamp of the first click or touch on a page.
This page could be loaded in a normal browser, or on a webview, so is better to use a vanilla javascript, without any library.

Is that possible to achieve this? Or I must use some jQuery or something?
I only would like to save the `Date.now()` of the first interaction.

Comment: you could try: `document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', function);`

Comment: legit, and for touches? is there anything specific or this just works?

Comment: Try this one: https://jsfiddle.net/ezqx37k8/

Comment: is "click" better of "mousedown" for using it to bind the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to listen for the first click you could do something simple like this:

```
window.onclick = function() {
    var timeStamp = Date.now();
    console.log(timeStamp);
    //do manipulations, send data to server / anything you want to do

    //unbind window.onclick (resetting it to empty function)
    window.onclick = function() {}
}
```

You can read more about `onclick` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)
**note** that this will unbind **every** onclick bound to the window object itself as you can only have one listener like this. There is however [another method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which brings the following advantages over doing this `window.onclick = function() { ... }` thing:

> 1. It allows adding more than a single handler for an event. This is
>      particularly useful for DHTML libraries or Mozilla extensions that
>      need to work well with other libraries/extensions.
> 2. It gives you finer-grained control of the phase when the listener gets activated (capturing vs. bubbling)
> 3. It works on any DOM element, not just HTML elements.

So this basically allows you to for instance add events like this:

```
//first event listener
window.addEventListener('click', function() { console.log('click1'); });
//second event listener (also a click)
window.addEventListener('click', function() { console.log('click2'); });
```

the above example will output the following in the console:

```
"click1"
"click2"
```

The [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=addEvent) for `addEventListener` is quite good to even tho if you need to support older browsers you'll have to tread carefully as there will be different implementations across different browsers.

For (most) touch devices clicks get converted to touches at a penalty of a 300ms delay to check for double taps, this is not all there but quite consistently implemented overal.

On MDN there is something about a [Touch Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) but if you scroll down there is no real support for it yet, other libraries implement code that uses mouse events that are translated to clicks by devices and use that with some object wrapper to fire off custom touch events, [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) is one of those libraries - this one is probably a bit smarter in the sense of it probably using real touch events if they exist but I've never used Hammer.js before for that matter.

Comment: looks perfect, the only thing I don't understand, is "click" used also for touch events?

Comment: @MatteoBononi'peorthyr' `click` events on different devices get converted to `touch` events. Not on every device tho and unfortunately it's quite inconsistent to check wether a device is a touch device or a desktop since they both report inconsistently that they are either so it's not really checkable in a reliable way. (updating answer with touch documentation in a sec)

Comment: thanks a lot, this is leading me in the right direction.

Comment: @MatteoBononi'peorthyr' No problem, you'll be able to return the favor to someone else too which is how to chain extends ;)